# A bounded set in the plane

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set in the plane described by the inequalities $x^2+3y\le e^y$, $y^2\le x+y$. Using Mathematica, I can see that the set is bounded. How can I prove that?

Answer (score 1):

This set is **not** bounded.

For a $y\in{\mathbb R}$ yet to be determined choose $x:=y^2-y$. Then the second condition is satisfied. The first condition now reads $(y^2-y)^2+3y\leq e^y$, or
$$y^4-2y^3+y^2+3y\leq e^y\ .$$
This is true for arbitrarily large $y>0$.